# Setting thymeleaf variable using th:inline always sets the variable to null

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I want to make a javascript variable that I can use with `th:if` in thymeleaf.

What I did:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var variable = /*[[${variable}]]*/ 'value';
    console.log(variable); //prints 'null'

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

When I check the page source this is how the page is rendered:

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var variable = null;
    console.log(variable);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Why `variable` is constantly being set to `null`?

Comment: Can you please add the coresponding controller-snippet to the question?

Comment: If variable is null, it means Thymeleaf is doing it's job (replacing `/*[[${variable}]]*/ 'value'` with the contents of `${variable}`) but that you likely haven't added `${variable}` to the model.  You have a misspelling, or you really are setting `${variable}` to null.

Comment: @Metroids Oh, I have to add `variable` to the model in controller? I am pretty sure that I didn't do that. I'll give it a try later since I don't have the access to project from home. Thanks.

Comment: @Metroids That was it, if you want to, post an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting `var variable = null;` in the source, that means Thymeleaf is doing it's job -- replacing `/*[[${variable}]]*/ 'value'` with the contents of `${variable}`.  Since it's null, you:

1. Haven't added `${variable}` to the model.
2. Misspelled `variable` somewhere.
3. Added `${variable}` to the model as null.